# Constructing a function 'while' that identifies when an object from **JSON** has an error

Tags: r, json, api, loops, while-loop

I´m trying to construct a loop function that catches a json from an API in R like this:

```
for(j in 1:700){
tx_i <- paste0("https://example.com/api/",bloco_i_final$tx[j])

txi <- GET(tx_i, add_headers(Authorization = full_token, Accept = 
          header_type), timeout(120), verbose())


conteudo <- content(txi, type = 'text', encoding = "UTF-8")

tx_i_final <- rjson::fromJSON(getURL(tx_i))

(some functions that bind this data.frames)
}
```

But sometimes,in loop, this function ends up with an error message:

```
Error in fromJSON(conteudo) : unexpected character 'B'
```

I want to build a while function that identifies this error and repeats the process.

**Example**:

```
for(j in 1:700){

#THIS PART
while(identifies erro in FROMJSON){
tx_i <- paste0("https://example.com/api/tx/",bloco_i_final$tx[j])

txi <- GET(tx_i, add_headers(Authorization = full_token, Accept = 
          header_type), timeout(120), verbose())


conteudo <- content(txi, type = 'text', encoding = "UTF-8")

tx_i_final <- rjson::fromJSON(getURL(tx_i))

} #REPEATS ALL PROCESS WHILE ERRO EXISTS
(some functions that bind this data.frames)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One trick that you can use is to implement the `tryCatch(.)` method inside your loop and then decrease your counter. For example:

```
for(j in 1:100){
  tryCatch({
  #Define the link with all positions

  ### Implement your method here!! ### 

  }, error = function(err) {
    #Print the error:
    print(paste("MY_ERROR:  ",err))

    #Decrease your counter to try again
    j<- (j-1)

    #Wait some time before try again...
    Sys.sleep(10) 
  })
}
```